# Link ID raster to the attribute table

Tags: r, r-raster, readr

I have one single raster with 59 variables, but when I open the raste into R, I'm only able to get the ID field through levels(r)

Opening the raster with ID field (1 variable):

```
r <- ratify(raster("./path2raster.tif", RAT = TRUE, count = T, append.names = T, att = NULL))
```

Opening the attribute table with all variables (59 variable):

```
attable <- foreign::read.dbf("./path2raster.tif.vat.dbf")
```

How can I link the ID raster to the attribute table to be able to export a single raster for each variable?

Answer (score 0):

What you normally would do is

```
library(raster)
r <- raster("./path2raster.tif")
```

It should contain the attribute table. To create separate layers for each variable in the attribute table, you can do

```
x <- deratify(r)
```